# Compressor melted hole in 5+ year old defrost drain pan, is compressor overheating a possible concern

Tags: hvac, refrigerator, appliances, cooling

It is quite possible that my defrost drain pan melting was just normal age/wear & tear but I wanted to double check that there is not possibly a larger issue with my compressor running too hot.

This is my defrost drain pan [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE23XwOM1Bg&t=41s) and I have the part and am just going to replace it. The old defrost drain pan clearly had two large holes where the area melted/eroded away and I am sure compressor heat was at least partly to blame. I would show a pic but I already threw the old defrost drain pan out before thinking perhaps there is a larger issue with the compressor running too hot.

I just wanted to double check, if anyone on here, thought the compressor was running abnormally hot or if it is normal to see a 4/5 year old defrost drain pan, that sits/hugs the top of a compressor, develop a reasonably large hole from heat over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not normal, if your condensing coils are exposed clean them a high temp on the condenser can cause this by itself, if there is a fan make sure it s turning I once found a dead mouse stopping the fan from turning but it is usually dust On the coils outside the box (under the fridge for the ones that have fans). There are other things that can cause this but I would check the things you can first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have clean the coils and I do understand compressors can get very hot, hot to the touch of course. There is no fan on this refrigerator. I am surprised the plastic drain pan hugs the top of the compressor, there is plenty of space under the refrigerator to keep the drain pan away from the compressor

Comment: They use the heat to evaporate the defrost cycle water, you don’t even know it is cycling into defrost or most do not.

Comment: yes that is what I thought, heat helps evaporate the pan, I think for my situation, the defrost drip pan is possible just an issue of age that holes developed because the compressor is hot but not alarmingly so...